# RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}],what does it mean?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

I find new version(V5.9) of Wordpress adds this line to .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Old version of Wordpress does not have this line. What does it mean? Can I remove it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947548/what-does-this-this-http-authorization-rewriterule-do
hope it helped you, blabla i need to reach 30 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using HTTP Authentication with WordPress then you can remove it.

If you are using PHP as an Apache module then you can remove it. (Maybe WP detects this when it generates the `.htaccess` file?)

*Aside:* However, since this directive is inside the WordPress code block (ie. between the `# BEGIN WordPress` / `# END WordPress` comment markers) then if you do remove it then WordPress is only going to "try" and put it back again later. (You should avoid manual edits to the WP code block for this reason.)

Having this directive in `.htaccess` will not cause any problems.

When PHP is installed as CGI then Apache prevents the `Authorization` HTTP request header (used with HTTP Authentication) from being passed through to CGI scripts (ie. PHP in this instance). This is a "security feature", to prevent the user's credentials from being passed to all CGI scripts (which might not be trusted, if you don't control the server).

PHP normally sets the `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` superglobal (and associated array elements) from the HTTP Authorization header, but if it's been stripped by Apache then it can't.

The `RewriteRule` directive in `.htaccess` attempts to "fix" this by setting an `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` environment variable to the value of the `Authorization` HTTP request header (this is before the request is passed to PHP). PHP then assigns the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` env var to the `$_SERVER` superglobal array. So, in theory, it's doing the same thing. However, depending on the server config, this doesn't necessarily work.

Alternatively, to explicitly allow the "passing of HTTP authorization headers to scripts as CGI variables" you can set `CGIPassAuth On` (Apache 2.4.13+) in `.htaccess` and this should allow PHP to see the `Authorization` header. However, depending on the server config, this might not work either.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#cgipassauth

Comment: Until I commented it out, I was tormented and could not pass Get parameters in links. 404 squeezed out

Comment: @МихаилСуходаев Although that doesn't really make sense, as this directive has nothing to do with the passing of GET params and neither should it conflict with anything else?! "404 squeezed out"? Your problem was likely resolved by _something else_. (?!)